# How to avoid dup documents in firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to check if a FB event already exists as a document in my Firestore collection and if not write the new FB event as a new doc.  My problem is when comparing the parsed graph request 'results' dictionary to the fbEventIds in my collection the logic is setup incorrectly and creating dups rather than avoiding them.

Logically how my function is setup:

```
func getFbEvents {

     fbgraphrequest {

         parse graphrequest results into an Event object {

            get Firestore snapshot of 'events' collection {

               //Compare graph request event id to event ids stored in firestore
               if graphrequesteventId == FirestoresnapshoteventsFbId {
                  return
               }
               else {
                setdata of new fb event in firestore events collection
    }}}}}
```

**Actual Code**

I've tried adding in DispatchGroup and DispatchQueue enter and leave commands after the dictionary is parsed and before the snapshot is retrieved based on other SO threads but it still doesn't work on my code.

```
    static func getFBEvents() {

    let graphRequest : GraphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields":"id, events"], httpMethod: .get)
        graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
        }
        else {

            if let dictionary = result as? [String: Any] {
            if let dictionary1 = dictionary["events"] as? [String: Any]{
                if let dataList = dictionary1["data"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                   dataList.forEach { dictionary in
                       let eventDescription = dictionary["description"] as? String
                       let fbEventId = dictionary["id"] as? String
                       let eventName = dictionary["name"] as? String
                       let eventStart = dictionary["start_time"] as? String

                        if let nestedDictionary = dictionary["place"] as? [String: Any] {
                            let eventLocation = nestedDictionary["name"] as? String

                //Get a Firebase reference
                let db = Firestore.firestore()
                db.collection("events").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in

                    if let err = err {
                        return
                    }
                    else {
                        for doc in querySnapshot!.documents {
                             let e = Event(snapshot: doc)

                            print("fb eventId: \(e?.fbEventId) & \(fbEventId)")

                            if e!.fbEventId != fbEventId {
                                print("event does not already exists, writing event to Firestore")
                            let newDocument = Firestore.firestore().collection("events").document()

                            //Create a dictionary for the event
                            let eventData = ["eventDescription":eventDescription, "eventStart":eventStart,"fbEventId": fbEventId, "eventCreated": Timestamp(date: Date()), "eventId": newDocument.documentID, "eventName": eventName, "eventSource": "FB", "eventLocation": eventLocation] as [String : Any]

                            //Create the profile for the event
                            newDocument.setData(eventData) { (error) in

                            if error != nil {
                            }
                            else {
                            }
                            }//close Firestore setData
                            }
                            else {
                                return
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }//close retrieve events
                }//close nested Dictionfary for place
                }//close datalist for each
                }//close datalist
            }//close dictionary1
            }//close dictionary
        }//close else
    }//close graph request start
)}//close getFBEvents
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I think I got what I needed.  Please comment if you feel this won't provide the intended outcome but after some testing it's working.

Basically I counted the results in the snapshot from the Firestore get query to see if that fbEventId already existed, if not I wrote the new FB event, if it did already exist, I returned.

```
  static func getFBEvents() {

    let graphRequest : GraphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields":"id, events"], httpMethod: .get)

        graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error took place: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
        else {

            print("Print entire fetched result for events: \(String(describing: result))")

            if let dictionary = result as? [String: Any] {
            if let dictionary1 = dictionary["events"] as? [String: Any]{
                if let dataList = dictionary1["data"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                   dataList.forEach { dictionary in
                       let eventDescription = dictionary["description"] as? String
                       let fbEventId = dictionary["id"] as? String
                       let eventName = dictionary["name"] as? String
                       let eventStart = dictionary["start_time"] as? String

                        if let nestedDictionary = dictionary["place"] as? [String: Any] {

                            let eventLocation = nestedDictionary["name"] as? String

                //Get a Firebase reference
                let db = Firestore.firestore()
                            db.collection("events").whereField("fbEventId", isEqualTo: fbEventId!).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in

                    let size = querySnapshot?.count

                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error \(err)")
                        return
                    }

                    //If size of snapshot is equal to 0, FB event doesn't exist in user event collection so write fb event
                    else {

                            if size! == 0 {
                                print("event does not already exists, writing event to Firestore")
                            let newDocument = Firestore.firestore().collection("events").document()

                            //Create a dictionary for the event
                            let eventData = ["eventDescription":eventDescription, "eventStart":eventStart,"fbEventId": fbEventId, "eventCreated": Timestamp(date: Date()), "eventId": newDocument.documentID, "eventName": eventName, "eventSource": "FB", "eventLocation": eventLocation] as [String : Any]

                            //Create the profile for the event
                            newDocument.setData(eventData) { (error) in

                            if error != nil {
                                print("There was an error")
                            }
                            else {
                            }
                            }//close Firestore setData
                            }
                            else {
                                print("event already exists")
                                  //Get a Firebase reference
                                return
                            } 
                    }}}}}}}}})}}
```